# Image format conversion from png to JPEG/pdf/gif using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a cross-platform application which runs on both mac and windows.The application stack using is Javascript,backbone,node etc.,.
I need to convert one image format to another using javascript.
If anyone has done before,Kindly provide help.

Thanks in advance